# Why I get a $rootScope error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selectize.js

I have a `Selectize.js` input and I will clean all the inputs when I submit the form, the **code works perfectly** but this error appeared in my console after I added a code to clean my Selectize.js. Anyone have any idea why this happens?

My code

```
var $mySelect = "";

  agenciasAPI.getAgencias().success(function (data) {
    var embedded = data._embedded;
    $scope.listaAgencias = embedded.agencias;
    $mySelect = $('#select-tools').selectize({
      maxItems: null,
      valueField: 'nome',
      labelField: 'nome',
      searchField: 'nome',
      options: embedded.agencias,
      create: false
    });
  }).catch(function (error) {
    alert("Opsss! Erro ao obter listagem de agencias");
  });
```

I clean my form

```
$scope.nome = "";
$scope.tipo = "Simples";
$scope.contatos = [{
      nome: "",
      agencia: ""
}];
var control = $mySelect[0].selectize;
control.clear();
```

Error

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.2/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:8181/lib/angular.min.js:6:416
    at r (http://localhost:8181/lib/angular.min.js:127:195)
    at n.$get.n.$apply (http://localhost:8181/lib/angular.min.js:135:208)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8181/lib/angular.min.js:285:230)
    at HTMLSelectElement.n.event.dispatch (http://localhost:8181/lib/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3:6470)
    at HTMLSelectElement.n.event.add.r.handle (http://localhost:8181/lib/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3:3245)
    at Object.n.event.trigger (http://localhost:8181/lib/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3:5578)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8181/lib/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3:11546)
    at Function.n.extend.each (http://localhost:8181/lib/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2:2882)(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:108$get @ angular.min.js:80$get.n.$apply @ angular.min.js:135(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:285n.event.dispatch @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3n.event.add.r.handle @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3n.event.trigger @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3(anonymous function) @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3n.extend.each @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2n.fn.n.each @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2n.fn.extend.trigger @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3$.extend.onChange @ selectize.js:1448MicroEvent.trigger @ selectize.js:692$.extend.updateOriginalInput @ selectize.js:2721$.extend.clear @ selectize.js:2810(anonymous function) @ controller.js:115(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:120$get.n.$eval @ angular.min.js:134$get.n.$digest @ angular.min.js:132$get.n.$apply @ angular.min.js:135l @ angular.min.js:87F @ angular.min.js:91K.onload @ angular.min.js:92
```

Comment: You're calling `$scope.$apply` or `$scope.$digest` somewhere in your code by mistake. This code isn't included here, so the code you've linked likely is not where your issue is located. As an aside, please don't use jQuery in controllers - only use it in directives (if at all). There is an angular alternative to the library you're using [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select).

Comment: @DanPantry This occurs in `control.clear();`
When I ommit with comment the error doesn't happens

Comment: Could you paste the code of `control.clear()`?